# Understanding Archiving artifacts in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

What I need to give Archiving artifacts field in Jenkins path jobs.
and I see each folder is created for each build which containing all artifact inside which is increasing the space on disk.

What I need to do for this?

```
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "ReviewWorkflow". Configuration error?
Build step 'Archive the artifacts' changed build result to FAILURE
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
Request made to compress build log
Failed to send e-mail to sgg7kor because no e-mail address is known, and no default e-mail domain is configured
Failed to send e-mail to sir7cob because no e-mail address is known, and no default e-mail domain is configured
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message above, you do not have a file called, `ReviewWorkFlow` local to your job's workspace.

From the help icon within the job configuration for archiving states,

---

### You can use wildcards like 'module/dist/**/*.zip'. See the includes attribute of Ant fileset for the exact format. The base directory is the workspace. You can only archive files that are located in your workspace.

It's important to make sure the file/directory you are archiving is within the job's workspace. To view the contents of a job's workspace you can,

- Click on the job through the Jenkins UI and then select *Workspace* on the left-hand side
- Append `/ws/` to your job URL (ie, https://jenkins_server/job/your_job_name/ws/`)

In the event, `ReviewWorkFlow` is a directory and you wish to archive the entire content of the directory, including sub-folders then you can use the wildcard character,

- `ReviewWorkFlow\**\*` (copy ALL contents of ReviewWorkFlow and it's subdirectories)

Answer (score 0):

If you build a Maven project (for example) which generates a war archive in the target folder, you must use this syntax to archive the war file:

```
your_maven_module/target/my_module-*.war
```

This post command is running in your workspace root folder, no need to include the workspace path.